# Merge two columns in the same table so that it is not repeated

Tags: sql

I have a scenario in which one of my table has below Col.

Table _A

```
Col1
India
Pakistan
Srilanka
Australia
```

I want data something like this in the output

```
Col1
India vs Pakistan
India vs Srilanka
India vs Australia
Pakistan vs Srilanka
Pakistan vs Australia
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Show us your research and attempt. And you have tagged both SQL Server **and** Teradata - which is it?

Comment: The obvious answer to your question would seem to produce 6 output rows rather than five (E.g. it would include `Srilanka v Australia` also). Is there a reason that the sixth row isn't in your sample/isn't desired?

Comment: Yeah you are right I missed to add that..it would be 6 output rows

Comment: @VinayakDas . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

The original question was tagged both Teradata and SQL Server.  This should work in both databases:

```
select concat(a1.col1, ' vs ', a2.col1)
from table_a a1 join
     table_a a2
     on a1.col1 < a2.col1;
```

If you want to use a string concatenation operator, Teradata uses the SQL Standard `||` whereas SQL Server uses the bespoke `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query

```
SELECT a.Col1 + 'VS.'+ b.Col1
FROM Table_A a, Table_A b
WHERE a.Col1 <> b.Col1 AND a.Col1 > b.Col1
```

Comment: That old style join has long been not best practice - use proper explicit joins.

Comment: `a.Col1 > b.Col1` is sufficient. If it's true, you don't also need to check `a.Col1 <> b.Col1`, and if it's false the `AND` wouldn't be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  acol1 + ' vs '+ bcol1
FROM (
    select A.col1 acol1, B.col1 bcol1
    from Table_A A
    inner join Table_A B on a.col1 <= b.col1
    union
    select B.col1, A.col1
    from Table_A A
    inner join Table_A B on b.col1 < a.col1
) t
WHERE acol1 <> bcol1
```

Comment: Good catch! Was forming a query on Postgres. Have to replace with acol1 + ' vs '+ bcol1.